# Update an Array with its Chunk (an array too) keeping index the same

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm in a situation where I need to update an existing array using its chunks to carry out the operation. I've a working solution but I'm thinking about performance and I need to know if what I've is good enough.

```
const parentArray = [
    {
    key: 0,
    customerId: 'customer 0',
    partyType: 'party 0',
    date: '2020-05-25T17:17:38.910Z',
  },
  {
    key: 1,
    customerId: 'customer 1',
    partyType: 'party 1',
    date: '2020-05-26T17:17:38.910Z',
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    customerId: 'customer 2',
    partyType: 'party 2',
    date: '2020-05-27T17:17:38.910Z',
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    customerId: 'customer 3',
    partyType: 'party 3',
    date: '2020-05-28T17:17:38.910Z',
  },
];

const childArray = [
    {
    key: 1,
    customerId: 'customer 01',
    partyType: 'party 01',
    date: '2020-05-25T17:17:38.910Z',
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    customerId: 'customer 21',
    partyType: 'party 21',
    date: '2020-05-27T17:17:38.910Z',
  },
];

const mergeArraysHandler = (parentArray, childArray, key) => {
    return parentArray.map((item, i) => {
      const record = childArray.find(record => record[key] === item[key]);
      if (record) {
        return record;
      }
      else {
        return item;
      }
    });
}

console.log(mergeArraysHandler(parentArray, childArray, 'key'));
```

So as you can see I have a method that takes in the parent array, child array and a unique prop I'm using to run checks. As expected, the method merge the two arrays together, keep the indexing intact and updates the existing array which is the parent array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not done with good perfomance, unnecesserily you again and again search in child array instead of indexing it by key one time. And it can be done easily

```
const mergeArraysHandler = (parentArray, childArray, key) => {
  const childArrayMap = childArray.reduce((agg, v) => {
    agg[v[key]] = v
    return agg
  }) // or you can use lodash function _.keyBy instead of this

  return parentArray.map(item => childArrayMap(item[key]) || item))
}
```

or with lodash function `keyBy` it can be done in one line

```
const mergeArraysHandler = (parentArray, childArray, key) => 
  _.values({
    ..._.keyBy(parentArray, key), 
    ..._.keyBy(childArray, key)
  })
```

Or if we know that arrays are sorted by key then the fastest code will be

```
const mergeArraysHandler = (parentArray, childArray, key) => {
    const arrays = [
       { array: parentArray, index: 0, value: parentArray[0] },
       { array: childArray, index: 0, value: childArray[0] },
    ]

    const res = []
    while (arrays.some(v => v.value)) {
       const ind = Number(arrays[1].value && arrays[0].value &&
         arrays[1].value[key] <= arrays[0].value[key])

       res.push(arrays[ind].value)
       const changes = ind && arrays[1].value[key] === arrays[0].value[key] ? [0, 1] : [ind]

       changes.forEach(ind => arrays[ind].value = arrays[ind].array[++arrays[ind].index])
    }

   return res
}
```